# Saving multiple $_POST from a single text form

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I have a page with a single form, and a submit button.

What I'm trying to achieve is when some text is entered it's saved to the `$_POST` array and outputted below. However, what I then want to do is use the *same* form to then perform the **same** task (albeit different text), but ensure **both/multiple** values are saved.

I'm assuming the best way to achieve this would be to save them to an array as the page is reloaded; but i'm not sure where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: @bretyLurch: If you want to save the data in database then you don't need array here. You can simply send the data using POST method and store it in database. And display it whenever needed.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is make some hidden fields and init  them with the data from the form, 
wich has been edited the first time.
Then when it is posted for the second time you could use the values from the hidden fields and the new information from the normal fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenFieldName" value="<?php $_POST['normalFieldName'] ?>"
```